# Como pegar o valor otido em uma função e colocar em um text, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções, text

Consigo mostrar no alert mas qnd vou colocar no text (temp2), não vai!

```
    function mostrarValor(){
         var escalaEntrada = getRadioValor('escalaEntrada');
         var escalaSaida = getRadioValor('escalaSaida');
         var valor = parseInt(document.getElementById("temp1").value);
    if (escalaEntrada === "celsius" && escalaSaida === "kelvin") {  
            resul = (valor + 273);
            window.alert(resul);
            /*var saida = document.getElementById("temp2");
            saida.innerHTML = resultado;*/

        }
     }
```

Comment: Tem a certeza que o elemento HTML `#temp2` existe? pode publicar também o HTML relevante na pergunta sff

Comment: @Miguel , sim ele existe, criei assim:  <input  id="temp2" class="temp" type="text"/>

Comment: Haa. Entendi, é um pequeno mal entendido. O input (self closing tag) não leva com `text`, o que você quer fazer é modificar o valor. Faça assim: `document.getElementById("temp2").value = resul;`

Comment: Por isso é que é importante publicar tudo o que for relevante e possa ajudar a solucionar  o problema :P

Comment: @Miguel Nossa, valeu. Muito obrigado! E desculpe, sou nova aqui rsrs.

Comment: Não há problema. Ainda bem que resolveu

Answer (score 0):

Os elementos `input` não têm `innerHTML` uma vez que são *self closing* (auto fechados).

Deves usar a propriedade `.value` para lhe mudar o valor.

Comment: Muito obg pela ajuda   ;)